# Most common vs the commonest

Tags: word-choice

How would we form the superlative of the adjective common?

I thought it was most common, but my spelling checker recognizes commonest too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how software tools are designed including MS Word. Don't worry, **commonest** is the word and many dictionaries define it.

> [commonest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/common) (adj) - *Occurring, found, or done often; prevalent.*

However, if you find it on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20common,%20commonest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,most%20common;,c0;.t1;,commonest;,c0), *most common* is more popular than *commonest* especially in recent years.

However, interesting point is, many people prefer speaking **most common** over **commonest** because if you say *commonest problem* it may sound *communist problem!* To avoid such ambiguity with such noun, prefer using *most common*.

Comment: That's a good point. I had never thought of it that way, but it could be easily misunderstood.

Comment: I like the Ngram. Very interesting. My theory would be that _commonest_ is often avoided simply because other superlatives are also discouraged - like [funnest](http://grammarist.com/usage/funner-more-fun/) – but who knows?

Answer (score 3):

There are two systems for the forms of comparisons of adjectives:
One-syllable adjectives such as long have long, longer, longest.
Adjectives with three and more syllables such as curious have curious, more curious, most curious.
For two-syllable adjectives there is no simple and rigid rule. 
Grammarians have listed some endings where system 1 is to be used.
But, I think, people don't have this list of endings in mind.
Though grammars say it is common, commoner, commonest
people prefer common, more common, most common.

I don't think  that the word communist has an influence in this matter. With "communist" you use different structures.
Either you say: He is a communist - or you say: the communist system.

I think people prefer "more common, most common" because it is easier to speak.  Say three times "commoner, commonest"
then you probably feel that hasn't the right "flow", somehow the two syllables with a weak vowel at the end are  against the flow of 
speaking.

Comment: By the way, this "simple and rigid rule" for one syllable and throw-or-more syllable words is as bollocks as all "simple and rigid rules" in language.  For example, "apt" (off the top of my head even).

Comment: Not very competent, your comment. You should say where you see a fault in how grammars explain the two ways of forming comparison forms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my thought on the subject:
Two-syllable adjectives are usually considered long. The comparative/superlative is formed in the same way as the three-syllable adjectives:

- famous, more famous, the most famous
- beautiful, more beautiful, the most beautiful

**The exception:** adjectives ending in 'y'

- crazy, crazier, the craziest

Comment: Hi, Ana. That's a great thought, but can you back it up with evidence?

Comment: Simple doesn’t end in “y”, and we use “simplest” not “most simple”.

Comment: Also “more solid/solidest”, “more awkward/awkwardest [example](https://www.dailystar.co.uk/tv/coronation-street-georgia-foote-awkward-17134416)”, “eviler/evilest”... there are probably many more that don’t fit this rule.

Answer (score 0):

The American Heritage dictionary gives the positive, comparative, and superlative forms as common, commoner, and commonest.

Comment: That does not really seem to add much to the existing answers which try to explain the underlying rule. Can you edit to explain more?

Comment: Yes, I am providing this answer as an authoritative reference to the issue.